# Is there a way to skin an extender on top of a control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a project where i want (almost) all controls of the same type to also have an extender set with the SAME properties - is there some way to skin the existence of that extender instead of placing it on each and every control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you can check out [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx) [adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx).

Comment: there is one downside to this approach - i will have to manually code the exceptions into the ControlAdapter
using skins i thought that all i would do is set a different skin id to the exceptions and have the skin for them not include that behavior